# Calling Java from RPG, can not find my Java Class

Tags: java, cross-platform, rpg

Trying to call a Java Method from RPG, I have been following the manuals [Introduction to Java and RPG](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/c0925076171.htm) and [Calling Java Methods from ILE RPG](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.pgmgd.doc/c0925076172.htm).

But when I call my RPG function that calls my java function I get the following error:

> Java exception received when calling Java method (C G D F).

Pressing F1 reveals the following message:

> Message . . . . :   Java exception received when calling Java method (C G D F).
>     Cause . . . . . :   RPG procedure HELLO in program DEVLYNLIB/HELLO received 
>     Java exception "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: JavaCallClass (wrong name:
>     test/JavaCallClass)" when calling method "test.CallStaticMethod" with
>     signature "(II)I" in class "JavaCallClass".

Here is my Java Class:

```
package test;

public class JavaCallClass {
    public static int CallStaticMethod(int number1, int number2) {
    return number1 + number2;
}
```

RPG Function:

```
 H thread(*serialize)

 D StaticMethod    PR            10I 0 EXTPROC(*JAVA:
 D                                       'test.JavaCallClass':
 D                                       'CallStaticMethod')
 D                                     STATIC
 D  number1                      10I 0 VALUE
 D  number2                      10I 0 VALUE

 D sum             S             10I 0

  /free
   sum = StaticMethod(5:10);
   return;
  /end-free
```

I think it may have to do something with my CLASSPATH variable, I believe I have set it right. My Java class file is at `/home/WAL60326/TutorialProject/test`

Here is my full CLASSPATH variable value:

> '/Plex/Objava/lib/obrun.jar:/Plex/WsydXml11.jar:/PLEX/JT400.JAR:/PLEX/WSYDUTIL.JAR:/Plex/xercesImpl.jar:/Plex/xalan.jar:/PLEX/XML-APIS.JAR:/PLEX/WSYDDWA21.JAR:/PLEX/COMMONS-HTTPCLIENT-3.1.JAR:/PLEX/COMMONS-LOGGING-1.1.JAR:/PLEX/COMMONS-CODEC-1.3.JAR:/PLEX/ADDRESSBOOK.JAR:/PLEX/NEXTNUM.JAR:/PLEX/UDC.JAR:/PLEX/P6SERVICES.JAR:/PLEX/MASTERVOCAB.JAR:/home/WAL60326/TutorialProject/test'

Comment: can you paste your CLASSPATH variable?

Comment: @kw4nta I have added the CLASSPATH variable

Comment: does anyone know how to call java method from RPGLE fully free format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the package name from the classpath:

`:/home/WAL60326/TutorialProject`

should do it.

Comment: without changing the `.class` files location of course. class files must allways reside in a directory structure that equals their package structure: `my.cool.package.JavaCallClass` must reside in `my/cool/package`. This is by the way how `.jar` files are structured internally (they are simple `.zip` files with a different filename extension).

Comment: You might have to check file system permissions if changing the CLASSPATH does not solve the problem.